# Passing Nothing as a value to a database?

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I have a table that contains a nvarchar column that allows nulls.

I have a method in VB.NET that has a optional description variable that is set to Nothing

```
Public Shared Sub InsertDescription(Optional ByVal Description As String = Nothing)
{
    //Insert Description Procedure Call
}
```

If I call this method like:

```
InsertDescription();
```

It fails saying that the procedure was expecting the @Description, but was not provided.  The only way I have found to remedy this is to set the default value to "" or to not make it optional and just pass in "", but I don't want to insert an "" string into the database tables description column, I want to pass in null by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [DbNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)

> If a database field has missing data,
>   you can use the DBNull.Value property
>   to explicitly assign a DBNull object
>   value to the field.

--
Doesn't this work?

```
if (Description is nothing) then ' Set SP param to dbnull.value
```

If not, could you post some more relevant code?

Comment: I tried this already, it said it can't convert DBNull to String.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the `@Description` parameter to [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)

**EDIT**

IIRC I think you need to change your declaration of `Description` to

`Description As Nullable(Of String)  = DbNull.Value`

Comment: I updated my post, I Changed the param to Optional ByVal Description As String = Nothing.  I tried DBNull.Value, but it said it can't convert from DBNull to String.

Answer (score 1):

Either pass `DBNull`, or in your stored proc declare the `@Description` parameter with default `null`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `@Description` to a null value by default in your stored procedure when declaring your input parameters. This way `@Description` will be optional.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcedure
  @Description varchar(50) = null
AS
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Database nulls are represented by `DBNull.Value` you want an if statement to set the param to `DBNull.Value` if Description = Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

declaration missing.

```
Public Shared Sub InsertDescription(Optional ByVal Description As String = Nothing)
 {
   //Insert Description Procedure Call
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using DBNull [search here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)